# Generate all combinations with unknown number of slots

Tags: c#, combinations

I have a text file full of strings, one on each line.  Some of these strings will contain an unknown number of "@" characters. Each "@" can represent the numbers 1, 2, 3, or 4.  I want to generate all possible combinations (permutations?) of strings for each of those "@"s.  If there were a set number of "@"s per string, I'd just use nested for loops (quick and dirty).  I need help finding a more elegant way to do it with an unknown number of "@"s.

Example 1: Input string is `a@bc`

Output strings would be:

```
a1bc
a2bc
a3bc
a4bc
```

Example 2: Input string is `a@bc@d`

Output strings would be:

```
a1bc1d
a1bc2d
a1bc3d
a1bc4d
a2bc1d
a2bc2d
a2bc3d
...
a4bc3d
a4bc4d
```

Can anyone help with this one?  I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a fairly good place for a recursive function. I don't write C#, but I would create a function `List<String> expand(String str)` which accepts a string and returns an array containing the expanded strings.

`expand` can then search the string to find the first `@` and create a list containing the first part of the string + expansion. Then, it can call `expand` on the last part of the string and add each element in it's expansion to each element in the last part's expansion.

Example implementation using Java ArrayLists:

```
 ArrayList<String> expand(String str) {

    /* Find the first "@" */
    int i = str.indexOf("@");

    ArrayList<String> expansion = new ArrayList<String>(4);
    /* If the string doesn't have any "@" */
    if(i < 0) {
        expansion.add(str);
        return expansion;
    }

    /* New list to hold the result */
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    /* Expand the "@" */
    for(int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
        expansion.add(str.substring(0,i-1) + j);

    /* Combine every expansion with every suffix expansion */
    for(String a : expand(str.substring(i+1)))
        for(String b : expansion)
            result.add(b + a);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is shouting out loud for a recursive solution.

First, lets make a method that generates all combinations of a certain length from a given set of values. Because we are only interested in generating strings, lets take advantage of the fact that `string` is immutable (see P.D.2); this makes recursive functions so much easier to implement and reason about:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetAllCombinations<T>(
    ISet<T> set, int length)
{
    IEnumerable<string> getCombinations(string current)
    {
        if (current.Length == length)
        {
            yield return current;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var s in set)
            {
                foreach (var c in getCombinations(current + s))
                {
                    yield return c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return getCombinations(string.Empty);
}
```

Study carefully how this methods works. Work it out by hand for small examples to understand it.

Now, once we know how to generate all possible combinations, building the strings is easy:

1. Figure out the number of wildcards in the specified string: this will be our combination length.
2. For every combination, insert in order each character into the string where we encounter a wildcard.

Ok, lets do just that:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GenerateCombinations<T>(
    this string s,
    IEnumerable<T> set,
    char wildcard)
{
    var length = s.Count(c => c == wildcard);
    var combinations = GetAllCombinations(set, length);
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var combination in combinations)
    {
        var index = 0;

        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            if (c == wildcard)
            {
                builder.Append(combination[index]);
                index += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append(c);
            }
        }

        yield return builder.ToString();
        builder.Clear();
    }
}
```

And we're done. Usage would be:

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join("; ", "a@bc@d".GenerateCombinations(set, '@')));
```

And sure enough, the output is:

```
a1bc1d; a1bc2d; a1bc3d; a1bc4d; a2bc1d; a2bc2d; a2bc3d; 
a2bc4d; a3bc1d; a3bc2d; a3bc3d; a3bc4d; a4bc1d; a4bc2d;
a4bc3d; a4bc4d
```

Is this the most performant or efficient implementation? Probably not but its readable and maintainable. Unless you have a specific performance goal you are not meeting, write code that works and is easy to understand.

P.D. I’ve omitted all error handling and argument validation.

P.D.2: if the length of the combinations is big, concatenting strings inside `GetAllCombinations` might not be a good idea. In that case I’d have `GetAllCombinations` return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, implement a trivial `ImmutableStack<T>`, and use that as the combination buffer instead of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I offer you here a minimalist approach for the problem at hand.
Yes, like other have said recursion is the way to go here.

Recursion is a perfect fit here, since we can solve this problem by providing the solution for a short part of the input and start over again with the other part until we are done and merge the results.

Every recursion must have a stop condition - meaning no more recursion needed.

Here my stop condition is that there are no more `"@"` in the string.
I'm using string as my set of values (`1234`) since it is an `IEnumerable<char>`.

All other solutions here are great, Just wanted to show you a short approach.

```
internal static IEnumerable<string> GetStrings(string input)
{
    var values = "1234";
    var permutations = new List<string>();

     var index = input.IndexOf('@');
     if (index == -1) return new []{ input };

     for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
     {
         var newInput = input.Substring(0, index) + values[i] + input.Substring(index + 1);
         permutations.AddRange(GetStrings(newInput));
     }

     return permutations;
}
```

---

An even shorter and cleaner approach with LINQ:

```
internal static IEnumerable<string> GetStrings(string input)
{
  var values = "1234";

  var index = input.IndexOf('@');
  if (index == -1) return new []{ input };

  return 
      values
      .Select(ReplaceFirstWildCardWithValue)
      .SelectMany(GetStrings);

  string ReplaceFirstWildCardWithValue(char value) => input.Substring(0, index) + value + input.Substring(index + 1);
}
```